# Error when compiling parse_command() function in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

My assignment is to create the function:

```
int parse_command(char *inp, int *argc, char *argv[]);
```

The function should:

- Split the string `inp` into words, and return the number of words.
- Two words are separated by one or more blank spaces.
- In addition, `argc` should be set to the number of words,
- `argv[0]` should point to the first word, `argv[1]` to the second word, and so on. Note: You should be able to print each word using the `argv` pointers

Here is my code:

```
int parse_command (char *inp, // original string
                   int *argc, // number of words
                   char *argv[]) { // array of words
  // Split the string inp into words (Two words are separated by one or more blank spaces)
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int a;

  while (inp[i] != '/0' ) {
    while (inp[i] == ' ') {
      if (inp[i + 1] != ' ') {
        inp[i + 1] = '/0'; // end last word (add a /0 to the last word)
        printf("here");
        (*argc)++; // add new word to array of words 
        argv[j++]; // argv(0) = i or j? 
      }
      i++; // it's confusing here
    }
    // The line I commented out below is where I get this error: 
    // array subscript is not an integer
    // argv[argc]= argv+inp[i]; // add letter to current word 
    i++;
  }
  inp[i + 1] = '/0'; // end last word 
  return j; // return the number of words (addition, argc should be set to the number of words) 
}
```

I get an error when I try to add a letter to the current word. The error is:

```
array subscript is not an integer
```

Comment: there are no 36 lines in your code ..

Comment: i think there is some formating problem when code appears after bullet point.

Comment: `while (inp[i] != '/0' ) {` --> `while (inp[i] != '\0' ) {` or just : `while (inp[i]) {`

Answer (score 1):

If you've got argc declared as an int* then line "36" should say something like:

```
argv[(*argc)] = argv+inp[i];
```

This way you dereference the pointer to integer and come up with an integer.

Comment: The OP actually commented out the line, but it's `argv[argc]= argv+inp[i]`

Comment: I'm assuming it is commented out because it causes the error (from the comment).

the argv[argc] is going to be the issue since the [] is expecting an integer between there. Instead, since argc is declared as int *, the OP is passing a pointer. Dereferencing this through by doing (*argc) gives them the int they need for the array subscript.

Comment: Oh no, you're correct (hence the upvote), I was just pointing you to what the actual line in the OP's code was so you could edit it into your answer.